# nginx: serving favicon.ico is failing to show on Chrome

Tags: nginx, favicon

Running nginx on Ubuntu 22.04. Website on a VirtualBox VM is up and running great.

I cp the favicon.ico(16x16) in /var/www. (16x16)

```
$ sudo ls -al /var/www
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root    4096 Feb  7 21:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root    4096 Jan 27 04:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    1086 Feb  7 21:04 favicon.ico
<snip>
```

```
    location / {
        root /var/www;
        <snip>
     }
```

I start up chrome and the home page (http://10.0.0.10/home) shows up okay, but no icon.

If I use a direct link http://10.0.0.10/favicon.ico it shows up okay.

I did clear the Chrome cache, shut down the incognito window and reloaded the home page. No joy.

What else can I try?

---

Update: added a missing link in the HTML. Used Chrome's inspect to ensure it was there in the  section of the main page.
Cleared the cache and reopened the browser. Also checked the access.log and if there is no request for favicon.ico

But no joy.

```
<meta content="Home page for website" name="description">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

---

Well something occurred and now it is being served correctly.

Comment: Did you add `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`?

Comment: @henrikstroem it wasn't. I added it but still doesn't work. See above.

Comment: Your website files should not be owned by `root`.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Sorry for the delay in replying. A couple of things, I have other files being served correctly even when they are owned by root. And the favicon is now working. I did not do anything except add the link as henrickstroem recommended. Magic occurred.

Comment: Actually figured it out. At some point in time, I accidentally deleted the location /favicon.ico  in the .conf. Put it back in and it is all working correctly everywhere. Thanks you all for your help!